# Add access to another project in Firebase

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Is it possible to give access to a different project in Firebase Storage? For example, let's say I have two Firebase projects, project A and project B. Is there a way to set up project B's security rules so that an application in project A can access Firebase Storage in project b?

I thought it might be possible to add the project ID of the other project in the security rules, but couldn't find anything like that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "[Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)" to define custom attributes on user accounts (which could be the app name), to be used as verification in the Storage security rules.(Note that this solution is viable only if a single project is used).

If there is a specific need that had the bucket and users in the separate projects, you could also consider "[auth:import and auth:export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth)" to move user account from one project to another, or coping the bucket data.

Your auth:import should look like:

```
firebase auth:import ACCOUNT_FILE    \
    --hash-algo=HASH_ALGORITHM         \
    --hash-key=KEY                     \
    --salt-separator=SALT_SEPARATOR    \
    --rounds=ROUNDS                    \
    --mem-cost=MEM_COST                \
    --parallelization=PARALLELIZATION  \
    --block-size=BLOCK_SIZE            \
    --dk-len=DK_LEN                    \
    --hash-input-order=HASH_INPUT_ORDER
```

And your auth:export like

```
firebase auth:export ACCOUNT_FILE --format=FILE_FORMAT
```

Comment: Are you sure that Claims will be shared across Firebase projects?